# Find the closure , Frontier and boundary of the following set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Find the closure , Frontier and boundary of the following set in $ \mathbb{R}^2$ given by

$$ S=\{(0,1) \cup (2,0) \} \cup \{(x,y): |x|+|y|< 1 \}$$

**Answer:**

The closure is given by

$Cl \ (A) =\{(0,1) \cup (2,0) \} \cup \{(x,y): |x|+|y| \leq 1 \}$

But I thing the closure can be

$ \{(x,y):|x|+|y| \leq 1 \} \cup \{(0,2) \}$ , because $ \ (0,1) \in \{(x,y):|x|+|y| \leq 1 \}$.

Am I right?

Also help me with the frontier and boundary of the set.

Comment: You're definitely right when it comes to the closure. As far as the bondary/frontier goes, how do you distinguish between them? I'm under the impression that they're the same thing.

Comment: @AlkaKadri, No there is a small difference between frontier of a set and boundary set as we can see from the example- "The frontier set of a closed unit ball is the empty set while the boundary of the unit closed ball is the unit circle".   That is, frontier set does not include the boundary

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. Note that most people use 'frontier' and 'boundary' interchangeably, but I assume you're using frontier to mean the set of boundary points not included in the set itself? i.e., $\partial S \setminus S$?

Comment: @AlkaKadri, Then the fontier set should be $ \{(2,0) \}$.   But can you tell me the exterior set $Ext (S)$ ?

Comment: It's important to look at your definitions. Write down the definition of the exterior of a set. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology), it's just the complement of the closure (which you've already obtained), but depending on what definition you're using there may be some more steps you have to show.

Comment: Your notation for $S$ is weird: you cannot take a union of two points. You mean $\{(0,1)\} \cup \{(2,0)\} = \{(0,1),(2,0)\}$ probably.

Answer (score 2):

The frontier of $S$ is (probably, your example fits it, and it is a usage that occurs) $\operatorname{Cl}{S}\setminus S$ (all points in the closure that were not in the original set) so in this case $$\operatorname{Fr}(S) = \{(x,y): |x| + |y| =1\}\setminus \{(0,1)\}$$

clearly:
$$\operatorname{Int}(S) = \{(x,y): |x| + |y| < 1\}$$

So $$\operatorname{Bd}(S) =\operatorname{Cl}(S) \setminus \operatorname{Int}(S) = \{(2,0)\} \cup \{(x,y): |x| + |y| = 1 \}$$

So all these sets can be computed/determined one we know the closure and the interior.